# Too much liquid released in canning tomatoes

Tags: food-safety, tomatoes

I'm canning tomatoes in quart jars. I left the suggested 1/2 inch of space on top. Tightened the rings. After processing, one jar has lost too much liquid. There is now a space of about 2 inches on top and some tomatoes are not covered in liquid. The jar did seal but are they safe to eat?

Comment: Are these "Fresh Pack" aka "Raw Pack?" Raw fruit has a LOT of air in it. The majority of fruit canning processes cook the fruit to some extent before canning it, which (among other things) removes a lot of that air. There's also a standard step of using a chopstick or plastic knife/spatula to release bubbles when filling the jars. Please [edit] to share the details of your method for this batch of tomatoes.

Comment: @Ecnerwal that feels postable as an answer